# Invalid reference format error while executing docker stack deploy command

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-stack

We are getting invalid reference format error while executing the below command:

$VAR=VALUE sudo docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yml service-name

However, the following command works without resulting in error:

sudo docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yml service-name

VAR is a variable in docker-compose.yml file

Can anyone guide me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sudo VAR=VALUE docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml service-name
```

The '$' sign expands the value so you don't want it on the left side of an '=' sign

Comment: Tried the following command:   VAR=VALUE && sudo docker stack deploy --with-registry-auth --compose-file docker-compose.yml -c docker-compose_dev.yml service-name results in the same error, invalid reference format.

Comment: Can you try only "VAR=value && sudo echo $VAR"? Do you get the same error? The best way to pass variables to docker-compose is to put them in a .env file. Have you considered that as well?

Comment: VAR=value && sudo echo $VAR results in output : "value", this is required to pass tag value of the docker image during continuous deployment. Tag value depends on the Build number that is being deployed.

Comment: Then the problem is in your docker-compose or Dockerfile. Can you post them?

Comment: The compose file works fine when the variable is not used.